# How to disable laptop internal keyboard

Tags: keyboard, laptop

I am using external usb keyboard. I want to disable laptop's internal keyboard using software.

I know that i can just remove the internal keyboards wire and disconnect it physically, but i wanted to disable it using software so that later I can enable it by just executing a command in terminal easily. I am talking about disabling the keyboard and NOT the keyboard layout.

I am having Hp-Compaq Presario A965 TU Laptop Intel Centrino Core 2 Duo(Freq. 2 GHz). I am using 64 bit Ubuntu Lucid Lynx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the keyboard via boot options:

1. Open `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` as `sudo` with your favourite text editor.
2. Add `i8042.nokbd`, preferably to the end of the file, and save.

---

Source: [Ubuntu Forums Thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=725199)

Comment: Is this just for this computer model or any model? And does this allow for USB keyboard to still work?  I need something.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/681260/446253 for a more elaborate answer