# Is there a way to disable a laptop's internal keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

A week ago, I spilt the contents of my cup onto my laptop keyboard. Half of the keys no longer work, except one! The letter Q which is very active regularly.

This is very disturbing as I work.

Is there a way to disable the internal keyboard of a laptop?

Is it possible with `xmodmap`?

Comment: What brand and model laptop is it?

Comment: it's `HP pavilion dv9000`

Comment: The most straightforward way would be to lift the keyboard and disconnect it from the motherboard. You can then place it right back down where it was, sans the connection. This way the keyboard will be disabled after reinstalls and you wont need to bother with software.
See this link, about halfway down the page where it gets to the keyboard: http://www.insidemylaptop.com/remove-hard-drive-memory-wireless-card-keyboard-hp-pavilion-dv9000/

Comment: Might also be worth taking it out, taking it apart, an cleaning between the layers..

Comment: "a user looks for a software solution, lets provide him/her with a hardware approach"

Answer (score 235, accepted):

You can use `xinput` to float the input device under X.

1. Execute the command `xinput list` to list your input devices.
2. Locate `AT Translated Set 2 keyboard` and take note of its `id` number; this will be used to disable the keyboard. Also, take note of the number at the end, `[slave keyboard (#)]`; this is the id number of the `master`, which will be used to re-enable your keyboard.
3. To disable the keyboard, execute the command `xinput float <id#>`, where `<id#>` is your keyboard's id number. For example, if the `id` was `10`, then the command would be `xinput float 10`.
4. To re-enable the keyboard, execute the command `xinput reattach <id#> <master#>`, where `master` is that second number we noted down. So if the number was `3`, you would do `xinput reattach 10 3`.

Here's a demonstration:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4004   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer CrystalEye webcam                    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
$ xinput float 10
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4004   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer CrystalEye webcam                    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
∼ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [floating slave]
$ xinput reattach 10 3
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4004   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer CrystalEye webcam                    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: I am interested by this solution! my xinput http://pastebin.com/puDxQaZ8 so I guess that would be it: `xinput float 14` This query is reversible? how to enable keyboard after this?

Comment: You would use the `reattach` argument to reattach it. `xinput reattach 14 3`

Comment: Perfect! this is exactly what I needed, you get my bounty =)

Comment: Perfect answer -  was looking for this too. any of the keys on my laptop stopped working so now  keep an external keyboard over it and it kept pressing the control key and what not. This fixed it up, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But after restarted my laptop, the keyboard is enabled automatically. So all the time when I on my machine, I want to do the above steps to disabled the internal keyboard that you have mentioned. Is there any possibilities to disabled permanently?

Comment: Wouldn't xinput disable/enable do the same thing?

Comment: What if you forget the master? `xinput list` prints `[floating slave]` instead of `[slave  keyboard (3)]`. One day I might want to use the keyboard again, how would I find the it?

Comment: @TommasoTheaCioni: There are only two masters. One of them doesn't handle keyboards.

Comment: As indicated in https://askubuntu.com/a/603717/833452, `xinput float "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"` works fine (id changes often). But for reattaching you will need the master id or name as 2nd argument. Eg: `xinput reattach  "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" "Virtual Core keyboard"`

Comment: Any way to disable a specific key of the internal keyboard and use that key from external keyboard?

Comment: This works with X11. What about a) Wayland and b) the console if no GUI is running?

Answer (score 44):

Here is a little switch button to enable and disable a specific keyboard.

First, you have to find your keyboard id with `xinput` or `xinput-list`.

### Bash script to enable/disable keyboard

```bash
#!/bin/bash

Icon="/PATH/TO/ICON_ON"
Icoff="/PATH_TO_ICON_OFF"
fconfig=".keyboard" 
id=12

if [ ! -f $fconfig ]; then
  echo "Creating config file"
  echo "enabled" > $fconfig
  var="enabled"
else
  read -r var< $fconfig
  echo "keyboard is : $var"
fi

if [ "$var" = "disabled" ]; then
  notify-send -i $Icon "Enabling keyboard..." \ "ON - Keyboard connected !";
  echo "enable keyboard..."
  xinput enable $id
  echo "enabled" > $fconfig
elif [ "$var" = "enabled" ]; then
  notify-send -i $Icoff "Disabling Keyboard" \ "OFF - Keyboard disconnected";
  echo "disable keyboard"
  xinput disable $id
  echo 'disabled' > $fconfig
fi
```

### Configuration

- `Icon` as the path of icon to display when enabling (for instance, `/home/user/path/icon.png`)
- `Icoff` as the path of the icon to display when disabling
- I used the following icons :

  [image: screenshot]
  [image: screenshot]
- `id` as the keyboard id (found it with `xinput`)
- `fconfig` path to config file. Change if you want to create configuration file in another directory

**Don't try to run the script if you can't run it again without the use of your keyboard** (unless you got another keyboard of course). Create the following launcher (in `home/user/.local/share/applications`) and add it to unity :

### Desktop entry (Unity launcher, Ubuntu 17.10 and below)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Clavier ON-OFF
Icon=PATH/TO/YOUR/ICON
Exec=bash NAME_OF_YOUR_SCRIPT.sh
Path=PATH/TO/YOUR/SCRIPT
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Utility;
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
```

#### Result

**Launcher:**

[[image: screenshot3]

**Notifications:**

[[image: screenshot4]
[[image: screenshot5]

Comment: This works well, thank you for explaining it clearly.  There is one thing that I don't understand: how to make the icon change according to the shell script logic. I think this determined in part by "Icon=PATH/TO/YOUR/ICON" in the Desktop entry, I have used an absolute path, "/home/.../icon_on.png" as I don't know how else to use a ".desktop" file though I can see that this may prevent it switching icons.  Could anyone provide a clue please?

Comment: Hi, you're right about the absolute path in the .desktop file. Sorry but I don't know how to make dynamic changes for a launcher icon. According to that answer, is not possible at all : http://askubuntu.com/a/244951/458410. The icon in my script changes in notifications only.

Comment: Ah ha, ok that makes sense, mine does the same, thank you.

Comment: A possible improvement: instead of storing state in a file you can check directly if the keyboard is disabled with this command: `function is-disabled() {
    xinput --list --long | grep -A 1 "id=$1" | grep -q disabled
}`. That way everything works even if the keyboard  is enabled/disabled by another program.

Comment: `fconfig=".keyboard" 

if [ ! -f $fconfig ]; `
Here,  what is `.keyboard` ? And the both the `fconfig` and `$fconfig` are same? And also what does `! -f $fconfig` means? I'm new in bash scripting. Thanks :)

Comment: `fconfig` is a variable pointing to a configuration file, arbitrarily named `.keyboard`. And  `if [ ! -f $fconfig ]` is a verification that the file named `.keyboard` exists in your home directory. This section create the file and set default config to `enable`

Comment: This is really great thank you.  I need to install `libnotify-bin` on lubuntu

Comment: The idea of the launcher icons is great once one may not rely on the proper functioning of the keyboard in the first place. I developed separate scripts for the off and on parts, testing the off part first and then editing that to into the on part.

Comment: Another improvement migth be to automatically get the id by the name of the file. This is what I use: `id=$(xinput list --id-only 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard')`

Answer (score 28):

Device `id`'s received from `xinput list` as suggested in [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/178741/284664) are sometimes somehow changed on reboot (at least on my PC) which resulted in disabling wrong device.

That's why I've ended using `device name` instead of `id`, e.g.:

```
xinput disable "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
```

Comment: Indeed _device can be the device name as a string or the XID of the device_ (source `man xinput`)

Answer (score 21):

For Disabling Laptop's internal keyboard permanently On Ubuntu, Need pass this `i8042.nokbd` Kernel parameters for not to check/create keyboard port

`i8042.nokbd     [HW] Don't check/create keyboard port`

Open terminal and run the following command

```
$sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Try to find the following line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Add parameter `i8042.nokbd`, the above line should be looks like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nokbd"
```

Update grub as following command

```
$sudo update-grub
```

Then `reboot` your laptop computer.

Comment: How would I enable again my keyboard?

Comment: @Rokibul Hasan, `i8042.nokbd` helped me a lot for my case.. in my laptop internal keyboard, some keys work and some not.. so I am keeping my external keyboard on laptops internal keyboard.. this causes problem at login screen. with your answer.. my problem is gone..

Comment: @GuilhermeParreira You must already have sorted a functioning keyboard from within your own user environment in order to proceed comfortably with the coding above. I did that and could still use the _internal keyboard_ at start-up for the **hard disk lock** and for editing the **boot-loader menu**; earlier, though, I could not even change the bootstrapping passwords, for the fields were filled by volleys of characters. This helped me. The login into the **Ubuntu system** worked via the _external keyboard_ only. Once you are in, you can revert the settings above in the same way you enabled them

Comment: Note that, once you disable the keyboard port, the command `xinput --list` will not show the internal keyboard any longer. So all bash scripts searching for the string **AT Translated Set 2 keyboard** will fail. This is logical because the keyboard has been disabled at a higher level than that the scripts look into. So you will not be able to reinstate the keyboard from inside Ubuntu in other ways than changing the boot loader configuration again and reboot.

Comment: Usually, I upvote posts just after get helped from the post. But this time I had to restart my laptop before upvoting :)
@Rokibul Hasan, thanks man it helps me a lot.

Comment: I did this. It fixed the random typing . but on startup its beeping like time bomb. any suggestions?

Answer (score 14):

I thought of 2 ways you can do this:

1. By setting up a wrong model for your laptop keyboard in xorg.conf ?
2. By installing [Lock-keyboard-for-Baby](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lk4b/files/lk4b/20080706/lock-keyboard-for-baby-20080706.pl/download)

`Lock-keyboard-for-Baby or lk4b in short, is a small program which locks your keyboard but leaves your mouse free. I wrote it because my niece likes to bash away at my keyboard whenever she sees me sit down at it. Keys typed on a keyboard can have disastrous consequences and I didn't want to lock my screen all the time with a screensaver.

When started, lock-keyboard-for-baby opens a small window which grabs the keyboard and echos keys which are typed. By default, it tells you what to type to quit ("Quit Now").

Unlike a screensaver, your screen is not blocked and the mouse still partially works, so you can still see what is on your screen - keep watching tv / video and/or read a document using the mouse to scroll.`

Requirements:

· GTK >= 2.x
· perl GTK2 bindings (perl-gtk2 or gtk2-perl depending on your system)

Comment: this is not exactly what I need, I need to use my usb keyboard, but your code is very useful! ;)

Comment: Lock-keyboard-for-Baby will let you disable your internal keyboard while mainting the use of the external

Comment: Brilliant. Lock-Keyboard-For-Baby works in Ubuntu 16.04 as well. I prefer to code using pen and paperbook keeping it on keyboard. This tiny utility solved my problem. For others, you might have to run sudo apt-get install libgtk2-perl before running the perl script

Comment: "Quit Now", Quit Now or quit now no worky under 18.04 with desktop tower USB keyboard.

Answer (score 10):

One sure way to disable it is to unplug the signal cable. You need to pop up the keyboard for that.  For information on how to do that, check out the [Maintenance and Service Guide for the HP Pavilion dv9000 and dv9200 Notebook PC](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01311536.pdf) .

Now there is a way to disable the keyboard using `xinput`. T do that, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

To list the devices your X

```
xinput --list
```

To disable the keyboard:

```
xinput set-int-prop 2 "Device Enabled" 8 0
```

To enable the keyboard again:

```
xinput set-int-prop 2 "Device Enabled" 8 1
```

If you get a error about permissions, use the commands above with `sudo`.

Answer (score 5):

Consequently, I discovered:

```
$ xinput float id#;sleep t;xinput reattach id# master#
```

> ***t -time to sleep*** *in seconds*
>
> ***id#*** and ***master#*** as mentioned ***above ([top of page](https://askubuntu.com/a/178741/284664))***

For example in my terminal:

```
$ xinput float 11;sleep 5;xinput reattach 11 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running `xmodmap -e 'keycode 24='` to disable just the Q key. If that works, you could add it it to your `~/.bashrc` or global `/etc/bash.bashrc` file. I got this idea from [here](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/09/15/faq-how-to-disableremap-a-keyboard-key-in-linux/), which shows all the key-mappings.

Comment: Wouldn't this disable `q` in the external keyboard as well?

Answer (score 3):

[Input device indicator](https://github.com/brandizzi/input-device-indicator/) allows you to enable and/or disable your devices from a menu. It uses `xinput` internally, but you do not need to open the terminal, list manually, type the command etc.

[image: A menu listing devices that can be disabled or enabled.]

It is in [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebrandizzi/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), so you can install it with

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 03BBACDA765F39D9A14EEDE4425F3F9343B40373
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brandizzi/ppa
sudo apt install input-device-indicator
```

To invoke it you just need to execute `input-device-indicator` (which can be added to the session startup programs) or look for "Input Device Indicator" through the HUD (or whatever it is called these days.)

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, based on previous answers and my own playing around, I created the following script, which I call `toggle_keyboard.sh` and place in my `~/bin` path. I have a keyboard shortcut that runs it set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

Some problems with the previous answers and benefit of my script:

- Relying on an id number with xinput fails when you reboot and the id number is changed. This happened to me when running `xinput float 13`. I ended up disabling the wrong hardware.
- Relying on a file to hold the enabled/disabled state will fail if you reboot as well. The file will tell you the keyboard is disabled (if you disabled it with the script), but after a reboot it will be enabled again. My solution gets the enabled/disabled information from a parsed xinput command.
- My script will work with any xinput device that shows up when you type `xinput list --name-only`. Just get the name and edit the top four variables. I use it for my laptop keyboard, webcam, touchscreen monitor and a few other things I use only once in a while.

---

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Toggle the laptop keyboard either on or off and notify the user about it

# Device name can be found by typing this command: xinput list --name-only
DEVICE_NAME="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
# The display name of the device in the notify-send popup
DEVICE_DISPLAY_NAME="Laptop Keyboard"

# Set these to the icons you want to use.
# If they are not found, the notification will still work.
ICON_ENABLE="$HOME/.icons/keyboard.png"
ICON_DISABLE="$HOME/.icons/keyboard_disabled.png"

function xinput_set_prop() {
        xinput set-prop "$DEVICE_NAME" "Device Enabled" $1
}

function notify_change() {
        if [ -f "$1" ]; then
                notify-send --urgency=low --icon="$1" "$2"
        else
                notify-send --urgency=low "$2"
        fi
}

# Returns 1 if device is enabled, 0 if disabled
is_enabled=$(xinput list-props "$DEVICE_NAME" | grep "Device Enabled" | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')

if [ $is_enabled -eq 1 ]; then
        # device is enabled, so disable it
        xinput_set_prop 0
        notify_change "$ICON_DISABLE" "$DEVICE_DISPLAY_NAME Disabled"
else
        # device is disabled, so enable it
        xinput_set_prop 1
        notify_change "$ICON_ENABLE" "$DEVICE_DISPLAY_NAME Enabled"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

xinput float "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"

After spending hours over years with different methods with different distros and releases. The above terminal command is what I rely on after problems..... I use this now with neon plasma and was using it a month ago in straight ubuntu 18.04. 
(needs applying after restart - can be placed in startup)
* My built in keyboard on my HP Laptop that is damaged and starts typing which causes serious problems - I use a wireless keyboard and mouse - touchpad is on/off as part of KDE topbar options - neon/plasma 5).
In system settings / autostart
A text file with the following line of code is saved as a .sh file and set as executable (txt files properties)
    **xinput float "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"**

The text file is given a name > keyboardoff > and placed in autostart (executable)
When you restart/start system > built in keyboard is switched off.
(use **xinput list** to test)

Comment: "After spending hours over years with different methods with different distros and releases." I did the same and I was always getting the "attempt to access private resource denied". That was probably because I was using the devide id instead of its name. This answer worked fine and imho is the best answer by far.

Comment: By the way, to re-enable that keyboard try the command **xinput reattach "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" 3**, where the number 3 is the id of the master keyboard (obtained from the xinput command)

Answer (score 1):

```
#Disable Inbuilt Keyboard on Ubuntu

# Find Keyboard Device ID
KeyboardID=$(xinput list | grep "Translated Set 2 keyboard" | awk '{ gsub(/[[:alpha:]]|[[:punct:]]/," ")}1' | awk  '{print $3}')

# Find Master Device ID
MasterDeviceID=$(xinput list | grep "Translated Set 2 keyboard" | awk '{ gsub(/[[:alpha:]]|[[:punct:]]/," ")}1' | awk  '{print $4}')

# Command to disable Keyboard
xinput float $KeyboardID

# Command to enable Keyboard
xinput reattach $KeyboardID $MasterDeviceID
```