# Dynamically change the application icon

Tags: unity, application-development, icons

The icon used for the app is in the .desktop file but is it possible to change this dynamically? You can change the count but not the icon. Is there an API for doing this like [OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/docktasks_cocoa/docktasks_cocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH3-SW3)?

Answer (score 1):

## No

There is no API available for changing icon dynamically . BTW you customize launcher icon using  progress bar and count

Comment: Does this still hold true? Or have their been any new developments? Thanks Tachyons.