# Flickering/Flashing screen problem related to keyboard

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, dell, dell-vostro, flicker

This will seems quite bizarre but that's a huge problem for me, I'm facing it for a long time since Ubuntu 12.04.

My Ubuntu/Linux Mint/Debian (Unity/Gnome) always starts flickering after using the computer for a while, I always thought this had something to do with the video board.

I have an Vostro 3550 (Radeon 6xxx/Intel Onboard).

First I realized that when I was navigating trough an website, when i selected with the mouse a  combo, the combo closed it self automatically then the screen starts flickering.

The i realized when i was trying to make the login in the terminal (crtl + alt + f1) a strange character appears, like: ^@ repeatedly.

When i keep CRTL pressed the system never flickers!

I have absolutely no problem using Windows.

What can i do? There is no such thing as Keyboard driver on Dell Support.

I would love to use Ubuntu only, but this is very annoying.

Problem happens on Ubuntu 12.04, .10 and 13.04
Linux Mint 15 (Cinnamon)
Debian Live with Gnome

Comment: Which system out of Ubuntu/Linux Mint/Debian do you have?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04 - All of them; Linux Mint Olivia; Debian Live 7.10 (gnome)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, I can add more information: - pressing the CTRL key stops the flashs, but in my case, the Alt, Shift and AltGr keys also stop the flashs.
- disconnecting the internal keyboard and using an external one solves the problem (more an alternative than a solution). For disabling the keyboard, there is this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard) using xinput float. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell Vostro 3550 (with hybrid cards AMD Radeon 6600M)

Comment: @corentin the same thing happens here! Also when I use it on battery the problem is less commom... I just gave up using Linux on that machine.