# Why is my screen acting up?

Tags: desktop-environments

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP Pavilion G7 Laptop recently, and accidentally uninstalled the "ubuntu-desktop" package along with some things labelled like Xorg or something like that. I immediately ran "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop", and it seems to have worked. However, even though I have the desktop back, something is going buggy in any window I open. In ANY window, when I press ANY key, the window blinks. In my chrome browser (which I am using right now), only the mouse blinks.

Could someone please tell me what I can do to solve this?

Update:

I have noticed some other weird things going on. When I press Ctrl-Alt-F1 to go to a fullscreen terminal, a bunch of "@"'s show up on the screen as if they were being typed one at a time. Now my cursor and programs are always blinking, whether I press a key or not. When I right click, the menu disappears after a second. When I select something on the web with my mouse and keypad, the selected area starts blinking. Also, when I press-hold a button, it doesn't repeat they key press. It's like a button is being typed repeatedly, BUT I'M NOT PRESSING ANYTHING!!! My keyboard is just fine! I still don't know why this is happening.

Update 2:

Now, my touchpad doesn't work! I have to use an external mouse now. :-(. PLEASE HELP!!! It's getting worse!

Update 3:

The problem just disappeared, but I'm afraid it will come back when I reboot, PLEASE HELP!

Update 4:

I found someone with the exact same problem: [Flickering/Flashing screen problem related to keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345325/flickering-flashing-screen-problem-related-to-keyboard?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get auto-remove
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**autoclean** - removes partial packages

**clean** - removes cached packages

**auto-remove** - removes orphaned packages

**update && upgrade** - exactly that

Reply if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: No, that didn't work. My programs are still blinking. :-(

Comment: I just found someone else with the same problem with the same version of Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/512767/after-re-opening-laptop-programs-blink-with-each-keystroke-ubuntu-12-04-dell

His question as never answered though.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this answer instead:

> Working! Just installing latest 3.15 kernel (I tried 3.15 RC8 and 3.15.3 from > http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/.
>
> It works like a charm!
>
> files to download 3.15.3 for 64-bit system:
>
> linux-headers-3.15.3-031503-generic_3.15.3-031503.201407010040_amd64.deb 
>      linux-headers-3.15.3-031503_3.15.3-031503.201407010040_all.deb 
>      linux-image-3.15.3-031503-generic_3.15.3-031503.201407010040_amd64.deb
>
> files to download 3.15.3 for 32-bit system:
>
> linux-headers-3.15.3-031503-generic_3.15.3-031503.201407010040_i386.deb 
>      linux-headers-3.15.3-031503_3.15.3-031503.201407010040_i386.deb 
>      linux-image-3.15.3-031503-generic_3.15.3-031503.201407010040_i386.deb
>
> Type in terminal:
>
> > `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

As found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457658/ubuntu-14-04-lts-screen-is-flickering-on-dell-optiplex-9010-aio-system).

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. I even rebooted.