# Disable laptop's internal keyboard ubuntu 14.04 permaneltly

Tags: keyboard, xinput

I am using a DELL INSPIRON laptop. Unfortunately there occur an internal problem on the keyboard of the laptop. It may short any key which self-pressed all time and reasonable some problems which is very awkward.
I use ubuntu 14.10 now and before I used windows 7.

I use this command at terminal

```
xinput --list
xinput float (#id) /* #id is get from the list*/
```

It works but regain the previous setting i.e. enable again when shut down and and restart. But I need to permanently disable the internal keyboard and when i need it back again then enable it.

Is there any procedure to do it?

Comment: I am also facing similar situation. Do you get any solution yet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to disable a laptop's internal keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

xinput set-prop #id "Device Enabled" 0

example : xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 0

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about what this is supposed to do. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)