# laptop internal Keyboard disable

Tags: keyboard, 17.10

My laptop's F1 key is being activated automatically , in prev version of ubuntu 16.** , I used to disable the internal keyboard by using

{xinput list

[get id of At translated keyboard 2   id=14]

xinput float 14}

But in the present version 17.10

'xinput list' doesn't list At translated keyboard 2

What should I do to disable the internal keyboard?

Comment: Dupe of https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard