# Ubuntu simulates keypresses/mouse clicks even after disabling hardware

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad

There are certain The issues strange issues I'm facing with ubuntu key/mouse events in my laptop. I had issues with keypad and pad due to which I am using additional USB keyboard and mouse. After the last reboot, it started taking fake key/mouse inputs (almost like simulating it) even after I removed extenal hardware and disabled the internal ones.

For disabling internal hardware, I referred to the following post:
[Is there a way to disable a laptop's internal keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard)

Even after removing extermnal hardware and disabling internal hardware, Ubuntu still takes false keyinputs and mouse click/moves. Please give some pointers to debug this issue. I could find no similar post as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was struggling to find a fix and after trying quite a few solutions, found one solution which is effective.

I did the following to fix this issue:

1. Reinstall Xorg:

> ```
> sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg
> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
> ```

2. Disable the touchpad driver (not external USB mouse):

> ```
> sudo modprobe -rf psmouse
> ```

With the first step itself, keyboard stopped malfunctioning. With the second step, touchpad was disabled and I could use external mouse without any issues.

Still, if anybody could answer how reinstalling xorg might have helped keyevent issues, it will be great.