# < key triggers without any pressure

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Two months ago my keyboard wasn't working well. In particular, the key <kbd><</kbd> starts writing without any pressure. I can partly resolve the problem by using `xkeycaps`, but it doesn't work as a permanent solution, so I presume the problem is not related to the hardware. How I can resolve this problem?

It is not the first and only keyboard that doesn't work, but everytime I change it, the new keyboard seems working greatly, for some time.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: The problem was my laptop keybord. I link the way to disable it https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard