# Is there a way to disable a laptop's internal keyboard permanently?

Tags: xinput

I have followed the steps in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard), but when I reboot the computer the internal keyboard is automatically activated again. Could something be done to keep the xinput settings every time I turn on the computer?

Here I have the list of input devices:

```
user@Lubuntu:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell USB Keyboard                    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 1.3M UVC WebCam : USB2.0           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Laptop extra buttons                 id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
∼ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [floating slave]
```