# Ubuntu keeps inserting '222222...' across applications by itself at cursor position

Tags: keyboard

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my old enough Acer Aspire 7738G and everywhere it keeps adding a string of "2" characters, i.e. "22222222" at the cursor position no matter if I open a browser, open search bar in Ubuntu, terminal, etc..  I am able to delete this string by hitting the Insert key and then delete.

Previously I had Windows 7 installed where I had the same issue and decided to install Ubuntu by replacing Windows (not in parallel), hoping that it will help, but no luck. I will be grateful for any help/suggestions.

[image: Auto insertion of '2' characters in search bar]

Comment: Looks like a sticky switch. Cleaning your keyboard ought to help immensely …

Comment: *Previously I had Windows 7 installed where I had the same issue* so this rules out OS/software. It's clearly an hardware issue as explained above.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it was definitely an hardware issue and disabling the laptop keyboard solved the issue. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem.

It's actually that your keyboard is damaged and you need to replace it or disconnect the built-in keyboard and use an external keyboard.

If it's too costly to replace the keyboard so you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVnUSmnom1g/) to disable the built-in keyboard.

So this is a hardware problem and all the software is good.

Comment: is this answer solving your problem

Comment: Thanks Keval, it seems to solve the issue at once. :)

Comment: its alright Sher, actually I have Asus laptop and i faced problem with insertation of 444444444444444444444