# How to disable Wacom touchpad

Tags: wacom

I have tried "Settings > Mouse and Touchpad" with no success, in "Settings > Wacom Tablet" there nothing related to it.

Comment: Please add more information about which model of Wacom you are using, and which version and flavor of Ubuntu. Click [here](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1365080/edit) to edit the question.

Comment: This outlines the principle on how you can proceed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard I don't know if that still applies under Wayland (Ubuntu 21.04) as well.