# Keyboard keeps spammming one letter even in grub/BIOS/boot menu (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, keyboard

Specs:

- Multilaser Industrial PC28X Laptop
- 4,0 GB
- RAM Intel® Celeron(R) N4020    CPU @ 1.10GHz × 2
- Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2)
- 62,5 GB
- Previously Had Windows 11, removed it and installed Ubuntu 22.04

Internal drivers -Input Devices- (From system profiler and Benchmark)

- Lid Switch
- Power Button
- AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
- Intel HID events
- Intel HID 5 button array
- ALPS0001:01 0911:5288    Mouse
- ALPS0001:01 0911:5288 Touchpad
- USB 2.0 Camera
- :USB 2.0 Camera
- VideoBus
- SZH usb keyboard
- SZH usb keyboard Consumer Control
- SZH    usb keyboard System Control
- USB OPTICAL MOUSE

Was browsing the web when stuff was acting strange and noticed my keyboard started to spam the letter `m` non-stop, even during GRUB, boot process and terminal. Trying to boot in advanced is not doable. Tried removing the key and cleaning the keyboard mbut didnt work. Already did a software update and a reboot, didnt work. I was using an external USB keyboard at the time, but plugging and unplugging didnt help. Tried searching for solutions but my case seems to be unique. I'm an Ubuntu Newbie,very happy with the experience, but i need your help to fix this issue,as i just bought this laptop.
Thanks, have a fantastic day!

Comment: Ate you saying this happens with the external keyboard *and* the built-in one?

Comment: yes, happensm with both

Comment: Looks like you have a hardware problem: That key is probably stuck. And since it's the built-in keyboard, you can't simply unplug it. Time to get it to a repair shop.

Comment: My initial thought was hw problem, but it’s happening with external kb as well as internal. However, unless the inbuilt kb is disabled, a faulty kb will still produce this problem unless disabled. Have a look at this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard to see how you can disable the inbuilt kb - if that gets rid of the problem you know it’s hw. You can then decide whether to repair or always use an external.