# Can not find ID for built in laptop keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard, 22.04, laptop

`(base) art_usr@artem--ubuntu:~$ xinput --list`

On HP x360 specter running Ubuntu 22.04 results in the following output, no matter if my external USB keyboard is plugged in or not. There is no `AT Translated Set 2 keyboard` device as suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard). Any idea what id would I use if I want to disable internal keyboard?

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:18                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:18              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:18              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:18                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet stylus:18                 id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet eraser:18                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-tablet cursor:18                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:18                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: maybe test? for example, `xinput --test 9`

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** From the output you're showing, it looks like you might be running Wayland. Threre's a good discussion over on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381944/how-to-disable-internal-keyboard-on-fedora-26-wayland) that might provide some additional insight for you. Good luck.